# Kiselev's Geometry Problem 102

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Prove Theorem: A median in a triangle is equidistant from the two vertices not lying on it.

[image]

Let AD be the median in the triangle.

Comment: think you forgot to add the question

Comment: sorry I meant to ask how to prove the following theorem

Comment: Ok, i thought that was the definition of the median

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means we have to prove that BX = CY where X and Y are the feet of the perpendiculars from B and C to the median AD respectively.

[image]

This follows immediately after showing the blue triangles are congruent.

Comment: You're right of course. Any line through the middle of $B-C$ is equidistant , just the points on that line are not. I'll delete my answer and plus you one.

Comment: @RutgerMoody I think the center of the issue is from the wording of the problem.